# Relative Layout and a Button to the left of a TextView - Squishing problem

Tags: android

In a RelativeLayout I have a Button to the right of a TextView.  The problem is that the text view gets squished to the left of the screen.  I want the Button to be squished to the right and the TextView take up all the remaining space.  I can't use 'Fill Layout' on the TextView because the button then gets removed from the View completely.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `TextView` `android:layout_weight="1"`.

Comment: RelativeLayout does not have layout_weight in the eclipse xml editor.  I am running SDK 5

Comment: Sorry, use a LinearLayout instead.  You can always place a "LinearLayout" within a "RelativeLayout" if this is what you need to do to line everything else up.